# How to start SmartEyeglass application from main activity

Tags: sony, sony-smarteyeglass

Is it possible to start a SmartEyeglass application from Android activity instead of selecting it manually on the Glasses Menu?

I have tried the code below but no success:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intents.CONTROL_START_INTENT);
            intent.putExtra(Intents.EXTRA_AEA_PACKAGE_NAME, "com.my.application");
            // intent.putExtra(Control.Intents.EXTRA_EXTENSION_KEY, Constants.EXTENSION_KEY);
            intent.setPackage("com.sony.smarteyeglass");
            sendBroadcast(intent, Registration.HOSTAPP_PERMISSION);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a sample project in the SDK showing exactly this operation.

Please check HelloWorld sample project. It shows how to kickstart your SmartEyeglass extension from the Android Activity and shows a message on the SmartEyeglass extension through an intent.